# Understand how to use Lambert W function to solve inequalities

Tags: algebra-precalculus, exponential-function, lambert-w

I am very new to the Lambert W function, and would gladly have some details about how to use it for solving inequalities when required (and I know it is for the hereafter inequality).

I have seen on the [Lambert W function - Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function#Solving_equations) that a general equation of the form $x=a+be^{cx}$ has the solution: $x=a-\frac{1}{c}W\left(-bce^{ac}\right)$. But don't understand the steps made in-between, and would love to, instead of using it as a "formula". Moreover, I am rather interested in the (weak) inequality case.

Hence, would someone be able and agree to walk me through the steps of solving algebraically such a general case of the following inequality for $x$:
$$ x \leq a + be^{cx}$$

Where all $x, a, b, c$ are reals. Moreover, in my case (if that would to change something for the steps), I know: $a>0$, $b<0$, $c<0$ and $x\in [0, 1]$.

Thank you,

EDIT: to maybe be clearer, I'm looking to understand how to get the solution - i.e know the steps - which is: $x \leq a- \frac{1}{c}W(-bce^{ac})$

Comment: There is no $x$ in your inequality.

Comment: Yes I switched it with $v$ instead, let me edit my post to be less confusing, sorry. EDIT: done

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$x=a+be^{cx}$$
$$x-a=be^{cx}$$
$$x-a=be^{c(x-a)}e^{ac}$$
$$c(x-a)=bce^{ac}e^{c(x-a)}$$
$$c(x-a)e^{-c(x-a)}=bce^{ac}$$
$$-c(x-a)e^{-c(x-a)}=-bce^{ac}$$
$\begin{cases}
X=-c(x-a)\\
Y=-bce^{ac}
\end{cases}\quad\implies\quad Xe^X=Y$
$$X=W(Y)$$
$$-c(x-a)=W\left(-bce^{ac}\right)$$
$$x=a-\frac{1}{c}W\left(-bce^{ac}\right)$$

Comment: Thank's a lot!! :)